# c++ save formatted dword to str variable

Tags: c++, dword

I'm new to C++ ,so forgive my ignorance.

```
_tprintf(_T("%4.4X-%4.4X"), HIWORD(dwVolumeSerialNumber), LOWORD(dwVolumeSerialNumber))
```

this prints out for e.g : 48AE-2022  .

i need to store it in a str var to write it to a text file. I tried to_string(), but it stores the number 9 which i'm guessing is the number of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TCHAR szBuff[100];
_stprintf_s(szBuff, sizeof(szBuff)/sizeof(TCHAR), _T("%4.4X-%4.4X"), HIWORD(dwVolumeSerialNumber), LOWORD(dwVolumeSerialNumber));
```

Or you also could do it C++ style:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::stringstream ss;
ss<<std::hex<<std::setfill('0')<<std::setw(4)<<HIWORD(dwVolumeSerialNumber)<<"-"<<std::setw(4)<<LOWORD(dwVolumeSerialNumber));

std::string sRes = ss.str();
```

In that case you should use `std::string` or `std::wstring` depending on your project unicode settings.

Comment: Saved me some grey hairs :)